# How to Extracted method in Scala inherit type T

Tags: scala, types

Let Say I have written a Trait

```
trait myTrait[T]{
  def plus:(T,T)=>T
  def times:(T,T)=>T
}
```

If my class want to use method that given by T.type, can I write as:

```
class myClass[T](val array:Iterable[T]){

  def plus:(T,T) =>T ={
    val typ = ClassTag[T]
    typ match {
      case value if value <:< AnyVal => 
        val numeric = Numeric[T]
        numeric.plus
      case _:customType =>
        CustomType.plus
    }
  }
}
```

I think by reflecting the Class is a way to filter some class,
but how to extract those method provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Scala is not designed that way. A simple but limited way is to have a "F-bound` trait the specifies the operation like this:

```
trait Plus[T <: Plus[T]] {
  def plus(other: T): T
}

case class MyInt(value: Int) extends Plus[MyInt] {
  override def plus(other: MyInt): MyInt = MyInt(value + other.value)
}

class Col[T <: Plus[T]](val array: Iterable[T]) {
  def sum(): T = {
    array.reduce((a, b) => a.plus(b))
  }
}
```

The obvious drawback is that you can't add trait to an existing class.

What you are trying to do in your example looks a bit like [type class](https://blog.scalac.io/2017/04/19/typeclasses-in-scala.html). And the way to implement it in Scala is something like this:

```
trait HasPlus[T] {
  def plus(x: T, y: T): T
}

case class MyInt(value: Int) {
  def plus(other: MyInt): MyInt = MyInt(value + other.value)
}

object HasPlus {
  implicit def numeric[T: Numeric] = new HasPlus[T] {
    override def plus(x: T, y: T) = implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(x, y)
  }

  implicit val myInt = new HasPlus[MyInt] {
    override def plus(x: MyInt, y: MyInt) = x.plus(y)
  }
}

class Col[T: HasPlus](val array: Iterable[T]) {
  def sum(): T = {
    array.reduce((a, b) => implicitly[HasPlus[T]].plus(a, b))
  }
}
```

Note that you "convert" `Numeric[T]` into `HasPlus[T]` by defining an `implicit` method that can convert one evidence to another. For a simple specific class you can have just `implicit val` as shown for `MyInt`